# Searching a varchar field for numeric values of a certain range

Tags: sql, oracle

Using Oracle SQL Developer v3.2.20.09:

I have a table of data where, among all the other data, I have a column of all numeric results (for examples' sake, `RESULT_NUM`) but due to the way it is stored and used, is a varchar2 field.  I need to pull all the records for the Body Temperature Codes (`BT`, `TEMP`, `TEMPERATURE` in the `VT_CODE` field) where `result_num > 100` (everything is in Fahrenheit, so searching on the result alone will work).

So, my simple statement is:

```
Select * from VITALS where VT_CODE in ('BT', 'TEMP', 'TEMPERATURE');
```

This kicks me back all of the body temp records, which is over 2M.  Now I need to refine it to get results that are over over 100.

When I try to add "and `result_num > 100`" I get an error because it is a varchar field I am trying to search with a number.

When I try to add "and `result_num > '100'`", it executes without error because it is a character value, but it returns everything greater than 1, not 100, which is everything, obviously.

Please help.

Comment: What error do you get with the first query? ORA-01722? That would imply you have data that isn't actually a number in that column - which is why you shouldn't be storing it as a string, of course.

Comment: ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P017
ORA-01722: invalid number
12801. 00000 -  "error signaled in parallel query server %s"
*Cause:    A parallel query server reached an exception condition.
*Action:   Check the following error message for the cause, and consult
           your error manual for the appropriate action.
*Comment:  This error can be turned off with event 10397, in which
           case the server's actual error is signaled instead.

Comment: Then you have have non-numeric values in the `result_num` column; not necessarily in rows matching your `vt_code` filter, it depends what order Oracle evaluates things. You probably first need to figure out why they are there and what they represent, and whether you need to fix them. You may be able to skip or accommodate them but it depends what they are.

Comment: Maybe because they have a decimal point?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: No, not because they have a decimal point, unless your NLS settings are wrong. An explicit `to_number()` or `cast()` might work but only by changing the evaluation order, and it might break again in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

`and convert(int,result_num) > 100`

or

`and CAST(result_num as INTEGER) > 100`

Comment: Convert option gave me an ORA-00904 error saying INT is an invalid identifier.

CAST statement seems to have worked.  Thank you!